# Laravel: passing variables from Route::get static page to view

Tags: php, laravel

I am working with Laravel and I am not used to it. Currently I need to add description and title tags to page (that are missing from existing page already coded by someone else).

I see that there are some static pages that doesn't have any controller but are defined also in routes.php. For instnace, one of them is like this:

```
Route::get('feedback', function()
{
    return view('feedback');
});
```

It renders feedback.blade which uses home.layout. I do not understand how to pass variables from this routes.php to home.layout.

If I would understand, I would be able to define some array like

`$meta['title']`  and `$meta['description']` and render those in layout.
It seems as basic question, but I really tried to google and no results.

I have tried like this:

```
Route::get('feedback', function()
{
    $meta = [
        'title' => 'About title',
        'description' => 'About description'    
    ];
    return view('feedback', ['meta' => $meta]);
});
```

and in blade layout

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0"/>
    {{ isset($meta) ? $meta->title : 'test'  }}
```

But it resulted in error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use some of the following options:

```
Route::get('feedback', function()
{
    return view('feedback')->with('variable', $variable);
});


Route::get('feedback', function()
{
    return view('feedback', ['variable' => $variable]);
});


Route::get('feedback', function()
{
    return view('feedback')->with(compact('variable'));
});
```

Then in the blade file you can use $variable as a local variable.

Comment: Actually I already tried like this, but when using in view it doesn't show. I have updated my question with example how I tried.

Comment: How your about page looks like?

Comment: $meta is an array and not an object so you should get the value like this: $meta['title'] instead of $meta->title